# Swiftui - Is there any way to detect if the app is allowd in SLEEP mode?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an alarm app which wants to reminder the user when they have not enabled the app notifications in System settings.
How do I detect if the user have enalbed app notifications in SLEEP mode programatically by swiftui language ?

Comment: You cannot access this information in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your info. But that is sad...